# Major revision: is it faster to revise or to submit elsewhere?

Tags: paper-submission

The style of the manuscript was reviewed as being inappropriate for the style of this journal (not widely known), though the results and contents weren't attacked. A major revision is needed to change the writing style. I guess the manuscript is too theoretical and domain specific for this journal in its current writing.

Choosing between revising the manuscript and submitting elsewhere, will the former be faster in review?

Comment: "The style of the manuscript was reviewed as being inappropriate for the style of this journal" by whom? the referees or the editor? And is it about writing or about content?

Comment: Without knowing the field, the journals in question, the specific situation, the required changes it is hard if not impossible to give any useful comment (useful = beyond trivial). Generally speaking, major revisions are an order of magnitude faster than submission from scratch, but this is the trivial part. The fact that the choice of topic itself triggered a major revision is strange. You talk about "writing style", but being "too theoretical" or "domain specific" is nothing to do with the writing style, it is the actual content of your research.

Comment: Voting to reopen because I don't see what's so unclear about it. It simply asks whether it's faster to revise after a major revision decision or to submit elsewhere. The first paragraph is unimportant; the answer to the second is simple enough.

Comment: @darijgrinberg by both editor and reviewers. about content

Comment: @Greg writing style can change the way one understands the content. the content isn't absolutely objective, and it's up to how it's presented

Comment: If they believe the content is off-topic, then why do you want to revise it? A revision shouldn't noticeably change the genre.

Comment: @darijgrinberg ur point makes sense. there's not a clear boundary between being off topic and mismatch in writing style. the reviewers say the topic is of interest but the contents are hard to follow

Answer (score 5):

It's usually faster to review a revision than a fresh submission. This is because of two reasons:

1. With a revision, you (usually) already know who the reviewers are: they are the people who reviewed the paper the first time. With fresh submissions you have to invite from scratch.
2. With a revision, because the reviewers have already seen the manuscript previously, they can review faster.

Whether you revise or submit elsewhere is up to you (however, if you choose to submit elsewhere, please do tell the journal that you won't be submitting a revision, for bookkeeping purposes).